# Facing z-indexing issues on absolutely positioned child div under a relatively positioned parent div

Tags: css, position, z-index, css-position

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <title>Test z-index</title>
    <style>
        .div1 {position:relative; z-index:1; margin:10px; background:#eee; }
        .div2 {position:absolute; top:14px; z-index:999; background:blue; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div1" >Lorem ipsum ... <div class="div2">This element I want to be on top!</div> Phasellus fermentum in, dolor.</div>
    <div class="div1" >Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yMcf6/

I have two elements `div1` which are relatively positioned.

Inside the first element I put an absolute element `div2`. I want to put `div2` element on top of both `div1` elements (all elements on the site).

The problem is that `div2` is on top of first `div1` element, but it's not on top of the second `div1` element.

How can I fix it? How can I edit my css code?

Answer (score 3):

Removing the `z-index` from `.div1` will allow `.div2` to be positioned absolutely over the `.div1` elements.

The problem you have is that each `.div1` which is positioned and has `z-index:1` creates it's own *new* stacking context, which do not (as you discovered) interact with each other.

Actually, if you can give the second `.div1` it's *own* rules, it is possible to have:

- first `.div1` `z-index:0`
- `.div1` `z-index:1`
- second `.div1` `z-index:-1`

but this only works because of the negative `z-index` as those are rendered/stacked under positive ones.

So, in my quick example above it would *not* work with:

- first `.div1` `z-index:1`
- `.div1` `z-index:2`
- second `.div1` `z-index:0`

See the numbered list in the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) for a description of the painting order of the different layers.

Comment: I removed z-index from .div1 - I didn't need it and tested it wrong. thanks very much it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Put `div2` outside the two `div1`s, and you won't need `z-index`.

Like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/yMcf6/7/

I have added some padding to `div2` in the fiddle, to make it clear that its on top of other 2 divs.

Your html should look like this :

```
<div class="div1" >Lorem ipsum ...  Phasellus fermentum in, dolor.</div>
<div class="div1" >Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
<div class="div2">This element I want to be on top!</div>
```

Comment: In this case I won't be able to position div2 relatively to div1.(the whole website will have a lot of div1 and div2 elements)

Answer (score 0):

give div2 instead of `top:14px; to top:0px;`

Will put it above the other line

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yMcf6/10/

problem is .div1 contain same z-index. z-index of .div2 which is inner element of .div1 will not effect to .div2. In this case, you need to extra one more class for .div1 as it contains other element.

like this -

```
<div class="div1 has_div2">Lorem ipsum ... <div class="div2">This element I want to be on top!</div> Phasellus fermentum in, dolor.</div>
<div class="div1">Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
```

and css:

```
.div1 {position:relative; z-index:1; margin:10px; background:#eee; }
.div1.has_div2 { z-index:5 }
.div2 {position:absolute; top:14px; z-index:999; background:blue; }
```

:)

Comment: it can happen that in second div1 may appear div2, that is why this solution won't work

Comment: yes, it wont. For that you need to specify appropriate z-index for top div and else no way :)

Answer (score 0):

So you mean you want div2 to appear twice?

once over each occurance of div1.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done (with CSS alone).

By giving `div1` a position and a z-index, you create a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). So the `div2` is inside your `div1`. Every `z-index` inside of `div1` has only a meaning inside the stacking context. The second `div1` and the `div2` are in different stacking contexts, so no chance.

You have to use JavaScript in this way.

- Move the `div2` in the dom hierarchy to the same stacking context as the `div1`
- Position it to match the previous position
- give it the proper z-index